# Rotational wavefunction for diatomics in the ground state

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rotation, spherical-harmonics

Frozen diatomic molecule looks like a cylinder. When it rotates, since it rotates fast, its wavefunction will have some symmetry, depending on the rotational state (which are quantized).

In the ground rotational state, $l=0 , Y_{0}^{0}$, we know that the angular momentum wavefuntion is spherical. Does this mean that actually the molecule is still rotating ( and not in the ground state, thus having some energy) ?

Since, if it was frozen, it would not have the spherical symmetry. Maybe, I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mike Stone's answer is completely correct. Your confusion comes from an imperfect interpretation of quantum mechanics (an interpretation that is very common, esp. in chemistry-oriented youtube videos on the topic). For simplicity, I'll discuss the wave function of an electron in a simplified hydrogen atom instead of a molecular rotator.

The wavefunction, $\psi(x)$, is commonly explained as a probability amplitude to find the electron at $x$. When not observed, the electron is randomly moving around, until you look. It is then found at $x$, with probability $||\psi(x)||^2$, at which point psi collapses to $\delta(x)$, or at least something normalized whose square is a delta function.

If you were to think about this in the contest of the hairy-ball theorem: you just can't imagine this random $\vec v(\vec x)$ existing in a manner that has zero angular momentum when average over the sphere, and you'd be right.

So where is the problem? The problem is assuming the electron is moving around with a velocity. That is just not what the wave function is. It is a far too classical interpretation.

In the 2-slit experiment, it would be like saying: the photon goes through one of the slits randomly, but since you don't know which one, there is interference. (Now *that* would be quantum woo).

Rather, the amplitudes for the photon to go through each slit add coherently. Likewise, $\psi(x)$, is the coherent sum of the amplitudes for the electron to be at $x$ with probability $|\psi(x)|^2$, and the phases are such that:

$$\hat H\psi(x) = E\psi(x) $$

which makes $\psi(x)$ a stationary state...unchanging with time, except for an unobservable global phase factor.

If that is a state of zero angular momentum, then

$$\psi(r, \theta, \phi)=f(r)Y_0^0(\theta, \phi) \propto f(r) $$

meaning the wave-function is perfectly spherically symmetric. If you rotate it, it is unchanged, meaning you really can't rotate it in any meaningful way.

For the molecular rotator: it's not rotating. It is just in a spherically symmetric super position of states (already described by @Mike Stone).

Answer (score 0):

In the ground state the molecule is in an equal  linear superposition of all possible directions, hence the wavefunction is spherical.  Were its axis to point is some particular direction it would have to have an admixture of higher angular momentum states, and would therefore have some energy and not be in its ground state.

Comment: This means that the molecules are always rotating randomly, and with increasing energy only the a portion of molecules with higher angular momentum increase in population. Is that correct.

Comment: I feel like this answer does not address the question raised by the OP, which they have somewhat reemphasized in the above comment.

Comment: No, in the ground state  the molecule is stationary, but  its direction is completely uncertain. This is just the angular version of Heisenberg's  uncertainty priciple in action. Remember  that the axis direction ${\bf n}$ and the angular momentum ${\bf L}$ do not commute.